# Circuitmaker - define board size manually

Tags: cad, circuit, circuit-diagram

Been testing out Circuitmaker for a few days now. Since I am a forme EAGLE user, I have quite a hard time figuring certain basic functions out. The most important one to me is the board size definition. 
Is it possible to define the board size just by typing in the actual size and then set the board size to those values? I know the methods for defining the shapes via lines etc. but I would just like to type in some numbers and set the board according to that.
Is there a simple way how to do that?

Greetings,
Lukas

Comment: Same problem here. 2021 is ending and no way to perform this simple task.

Answer (score -3):

Home | Board | Board Shape » Edit Board Shape.

drag with handles and look at bottom left to see the size

Comment: There is no such menu and it doesn't provide the solution asked, typing the number in.